# Code module returning "unhashable type: list" error when sending result through Fast API

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fastapi, python-collections

I've written a python code to check the unique values of the specified column names from a pandas dataframe.

**Main Code:**

## Checking the unique values & the frequency of their occurence

```
def uniq_fun(df, col_name):
    try:
        logging.info(f"Calculating the unique values and frequency for column '{col_name}'...")
        uniq_freq = df[col_name].value_counts(ascending=False)
        logging.info(f"Returning unique values and frequency for column '{col_name}' in a dictionary.")
        return uniq_freq.to_dict()
    
    except KeyError as e:
        logging.error(f"Column '{col_name}' not found in the dataframe: {e}")
        
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred while calculating the unique values and frequency for column '{col_name}': {e}")

def cleaning_and_analysis(filepath, operation=None, raw_data=None):

    file_extension = os.path.splitext(filepath)[1]
    
    if file_extension == '.csv':
        csv_dataframe = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding='utf-8')
    
    result = {}
    if raw_data is not None and isinstance(raw_data, list):
        for i in raw_data:
             if operation=='uniqueValueFreq':   
                unique_value_freq_input= i
                result12= uniq_fun(csv_dataframe, unique_value_freq_input)
                ***if not result:
                     result[operation] = [(tuple(unique_value_freq_input), result12)]
                else:
                     result[operation].append((tuple(unique_value_freq_input), result12))***
```

**API Code:**

```
from typing import Union
from typing import Optional
import uvicorn

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from Data_Cleaning import cleaning_and_analysis
from typing import Any, Optional

app = FastAPI()

class Item(BaseModel):
    filepath: str
    operation: Optional[str] = None
    operand: Optional[Union[list, dict, str, tuple]] = None

@app.post("/data_cleaning_route")
async def data_cleaning(item: Item):
    filepath = item.filepath
    operation_name = item.operation
    operands = item.operand
    cleaned_data = {} # initialize cleaned_data to an empty dictionary
    if operands is not None and len(operands) >= 1:
   
        for operand in operands:
            
            if isinstance(operand, dict): # check if i is a dictionary

              for operation_name,operand_values in operand.items():
                    cleaned_data.update(cleaning_and_analysis(filepath, operation=operation_name, raw_data=operand_values))
        return cleaned_data
    
    else:
        data_clean_var2 = cleaning_and_analysis(filepath=item.filepath, operation=item.operation)
        #print(data_clean_var2)
        return data_clean_var2       
                    


if __name__ == "__main__": 
     uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

**Postman Payload:**

```
{
"filepath": "C:/Downloads/shootings.csv",

"operand":[ {"uniqueValueFreq":[["flee"], ["race"]]}
           ]
}
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What I've tried:

I converted the highlighted part from **Main Code** which was previously a dictionary, to a tuple. The same error continues. How do I fix this? The error is exactly at:

**result[operation] = [(tuple(unique_value_freq_input), result12)]**

**Debugging Info:**

*API debugging*

```
print(filepath)
print(operation_name)
print(operand_values)

C:/shootings.csv
uniqueValueFreq
[['flee'], ['race']]
```

As we can see above, the API is able to read the postman inputs.

*Main Code debugging:*

```
print(result12)
```

Output: `[(('flee',), {('Not fleeing',): 3073, ('Car',): 820, ('Foot',): 642, ('Other',): 360}), (('race',), {('White',): 2476, ('Black',): 1298, ('Hispanic',): 902, ('Asian',): 93, ('Native',): 78, ('Other',): 48})]`

This is the expected output. Not getting this when returning via API.

Note: Please let me know if any more inputs are needed to answer my query.

Comment: Yes - tell us which line the error was in. Show us the traceback. Ideally, print out the variables that it was trying to hash.

Comment: The error 'Unhashable List' is from these lines (I also highlighted these lines in my question):

if not result:
                     result[operation] = [(tuple(unique_value_freq_input), result12)]
                else:
                     result[operation].append((tuple(unique_value_freq_input), result12))

I printed result12 & it is giving the right output. I'm not getting the output from the API call.

Comment: Hmmmm... (A) The question `which line` expects an answer of a single line, not 4 lines. (B) We did not want you to print out the variables and _decide if they are right_. We wanted you to display the printout of the variables. In particular, what exactly is the value of `operation`? Show us, don't tell us whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: I updated my question to show the debugging results. The expected output is displayed via "print", but not through the API. And the API is able to read the payload. Please go through the "Error". Thank you.

Comment: @Apoorva what happens if you add `print(f'{type(result)} result[{operation!r}] = [(tuple({unique_value_freq_input!r}), {result12!r})]')` before *`if not result:`* just to see *exactly* what's happening at the error line?

Comment: <class 'dict'> result['uniqueValueFreq'] = [(tuple(['flee']), {('Not fleeing',): 3073, ('Car',): 820, ('Foot',): 642, ('Other',): 360})]

<class 'dict'> result['uniqueValueFreq'] = [(tuple(['race']), {('White',): 2476, ('Black',): 1298, ('Hispanic',): 902, ('Asian',): 93, ('Native',): 78, ('Other',): 48})]

Error: Unhashable type: 'list' @ result[operation] = [(tuple(unique_value_freq_input), result12)].

Comment: @Apoorva this is very strange - if you run the printed statement, it doesn't raise any errors at all...I was wondering if the value of `operation` had changed somehow [since that can be the only reason for Unhashable Type Error on that line...] But it's still a string so this doesn't make any sense

Comment: No, I checked that as well. No issue with the value of operation. The issue has to be with the API code. On postman I'm getting the 'Internal Server Error'. And no issue with the route names either. This works for some other modules.

Comment: I think the issue is with the looping within API, because the code works for the modules whose each input contains multiple values, example-                                        "operand": [{"fillWithDesiredValue": [["sod",999], ["rbc","great"]]}]. In case of single input for an operation like the one in question,                                                           
"operand":[ {"uniqueValueFreq":[["flee"],["race"]]},  where each input requires only a single value, the error in the question arises.

Comment: still doesn't make sense why the unhashable type error would be raised on *that* line. especially since it's inside an `if` block that ensures a specific key